# Download and unzip file asynchronically

Tags: c#, async-await, httprequest, unzip

So far here's my code:

```
async Task<bool> HttpDownloadAndUnzip(string requestUri, string directoryToUnzip) 
{
  using var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(requestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
  if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return false;

  using var streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
  using var zip = new ZipArchive(streamToReadFrom); // Blocks! 

  zip.ExtractToDirectory(directoryToUnzip);
  return true;
}
```

What I see tracing with the debugger is that the `ZipArchive` constructor blocks until the entire file is downloaded from the URI

This makes the bulk of the operation synchronous whereas I want both downloading and unzipping to be asynchronous.

What is the solution here ? how to make unzipping async ?

PS would be nice to have `ExtractToDirectory` async as well

Comment: Have you tried using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=net-5.0 ?

Comment: `is that the ZipArchive constructor blocks until the entire file is downloaded from the URI` Tell us what you mean by `blocks`. Do you mean the constructor doesn't _start_ until it is downloaded? Or it doesn't _finish_?

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in `await Task.Run`?

Comment: @njwills doesn't finish .. basically I can't `await` the constructor which is where (surprisingly) the whole stream seems to be read into memory

Comment: Well what do you expect? How could it work _without the whole stream_?

Comment: I expect to have an asynchronous unzipping similar to `GetStreamAsync` .. a "`GetUnzippedStreamAsync`"

Comment: Do the docs say it works like that?

Comment: can you save it to disk and unpack it with a different app / process? I mean you should decouple "download" and "unpack/unzip"

Comment: @GlennFerrie that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid .. I was hoping for a "pipe" that downloads and unzips

Comment: It doesn't do what you hope. I mean, it does - but not in the way you want.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1541

Comment: The directory listing of a zip file is at the end of the file. You could `.CopyAsync` into a memory stream.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman No need for an explicit memory stream, removing `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` would surely use a memory stream behind the covers?

Comment: As a side note, the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application.

Comment: Does the server here support Content-Range requests? If so there is a way to do what you want by subclassing `Stream`. Otherwise as others have noted you won't be able to do anything without fully downloading the file first.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes for sure, it was just written like this for the question

Comment: "How could it work without the whole stream?" @kofifus if the server supports `Content-Range` he could sub-class `Stream` to be seekable and use HTTP GETs and `Content-Range` headers to retrieve only the requested contents. Then he could feed that stream to `ZipArchive` and `ZipArchive` would not download the entire stream just to construct, any more so than it would read the entire contents into memory if given a `FileStream`. The only reason it's doing so now is because the stream coming from `ReadAsStreamAsync` is not seekable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ZipArchive` support in .NET only has some very basic asynchronous support.

You could download the stream into memory asynchronously (by removing `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`), and then do the unzipping:

```
async Task<bool> HttpDownloadAndUnzip(string requestUri, string directoryToUnzip) 
{
  using var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(requestUri);
  if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return false;

  using var streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
  using var zip = new ZipArchive(streamToReadFrom);
  zip.ExtractToDirectory(directoryToUnzip);
  return true;
}
```

I'm not aware of any asynchronous implementations of `ExtractToDirectory` in the BCL or any .NET library.

Comment: If I understand correctly the main difference here is that you removed HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead ? can you please edit your answer to make that clear ?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is to wrap your blocking code in

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // blocking code goes here
});
```

It will still wait for the entire file to download before being viewable, but it will be `async`.

To be able to view the contents of a partially downloaded file would require you to write your own unzipper.

Comment: ok thanks, so there is no way to get an equivalent of a "pipe" ("GetUnzippedStreamAsync")

Comment: No, there is not. You would have to create such a thing and probably have to get really low level with it, like parsing the stream bit by bit.

Comment: would Task.Run mess up any exceptions thrown during unzipping ?

Comment: Without actually testing, I can not give a definite answer, but in a general sense, it should not.  `Task.Run` should bubble up any exceptions that are thrown inside it. The only one that would certainly not, is an `Overflow Exception`... but that exception will break anything anywhere